# Android: can DatePickerDialog use addContentView(),or make the message field scrollable?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, datepickerdialog, android-framelayout

I need to add a `TextView` to append some message below the OK button,or make the message field scrollable. For sometimes the message may be too long and make [Cancel], [OK] button out of screen. I tried a few ways. The `addContentView()` should be the normal way to accomplish, but it shows nothing of the `TextView tv`.
Here the codes are:

```
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment{
    ...        
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String message = getArguments().getString("message");
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(mActivity, mListener, year, month, day);
    dpd.setTitle(message);  
    //dpd.setMessage(message);  //easiest way to show message here, but it may make [Cancel], [OK] button out of screen

    TextView tv = new TextView(mActivity);
    tv.setText(message);
    tv.setTextSize(16);
    tv.setPadding(48,0,0,0);
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams FLparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    FLparams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    tv.setLayoutParams(FLparams);
    //dpd.getDatePicker().addView(tv,FLparams);    //This will show message above [Cancel], [OK], overlaying the calendar. Not clear to users.
    dpd.addContentView(tv, FLparams);  //this show nothing

    return dpd;
}
```

}

Comment: If you don't need to override the cancel/ok button you can simply override onCreateView instead of onCreateDialog and return the View you want to show (without layoutparameters)

Comment: @Marcos, I've tried onCreateView() as below, but the View form super.onCreateView() is null. do you have another way?
View vvv = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); //this is null here. because it inflate nothing
        LinearLayout lll = (LinearLayout) vvv;
        TextView tv = new TextView(mActivity);
        tv.setText("Test");
        lll.addView(tv);
        return lll;

Comment: The implementation of super.onCreateView is null cause Fragments can have a null View, so instead, create the view you want to be the CONTENT of the dialog (the frame and positive/negative buttons will be created elsewhere) with View vvv = new LinearLayout(context) or inflate from XML with View vvv = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.vvv, container, false)

Comment: @Marcos, You can see what I want is a DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(...), without other layout xml.

Comment: Now I noticed you are returning another dialog there, when I did needed this I inflated a view in onCreateView and it contains a DatePicker that is a widget instead of using the DatePickerDialog